# Recommendations for leak proof containers?

Tags: storage-method

I regularly take lunch to work which requires a leak-proof container. The food doesn't necessarily need to be kept hot or particularly cold. An example meal would be a bean salad.

I am struggling to find a container that is leak proof.  The container will be upended and shaken (not too much!) when in transit from home to work. The container will ideally have a wide mouth to allow me to eat directly from it.

Have you got any suggestions for a suitable container of capacity approximately 500 mL (17oz)?

Answer (score 3):

I hate storing food in plastic, so the best option I found and use myself is http://www.bedbathandbeyond.com/product.asp?sku=112870 which does have a plastic top and silicone gasket but is otherwise glass. Been using for 3-4 years and love them. No leaking problems.

Comment: Love GlassLock products. We started buying them and have gradually phased out the rest of our containers. One note though... Costco (at least here in Canada) sells GlassLock containers that are stackable. I have not seem them anywhere else and it's a very awesome feature, as it makes storing these things much easier.

Answer (score 1):

I have found two types of containers which work for this. First, there are containsers as lemontwist recommends, where the body is either glass or plastic, but the lid has a gasket and a secure-closing system which prevents leaks. There are multiple brands which sell them. Second, for such small sizes you can use a jam jar with a screw-on lid. Both work really well, but you might consider placing the whole container in a small plastic bag in case you don't seal it properly before transport.

Comment: I love using mason jars but I can never get the lids on tight enough to avoid leaks (unless it's a preserve I haven't opened yet). I wonder if there is a better sealing cap out there somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where in the world you are, but an excellent leak proof system is made here in New Zealand called [Kip It by Sistema](http://www.sistema.co.nz)

What makes them good for your purpose is that they have a proper gasket with a 100% seal. The gasket can be simply removed from the lid (pop out with a toothpick) for proper cleaning

You can find it online on the local [trade site](http://www.trademe.co.nz/Browse/SearchResults.aspx?&cid=4&searchType=&searchString=sistema&x=0&y=0&searchregion=100&type=Search&sort_order=&redirectFromAll=False&rptpath=all&generalSearch_keypresses=25&generalSearch_suggested=0) in NZ dollars, or Google your own country for a supplier?

.

Note: I do not work for Sistema, just a happy customer

Answer (score 0):

I am going to answer my own question. Many thanks to all who offered suggestions.

We bought a pair of 470mL (15oz) plastic containers from Lock & Lock.

They were a reasonable price, made from plastic (I didn't want glass owing to the risk of shattering during transit) and I can confirm, leakproof.